# Connecting Teleport to Mongodb in cloud via mongos analog

Tags: database, mongodb, kubernetes, teleport

In my case, I need to connect gravitational Teleport to mongodb in the cloud through an application deployed in kubernetes.
For postgresql, I used Pgbouncer which, using user/password, connected to postgresql in the cloud, and a teleport was connected to it using a certificate. For mongodb, I found a solution with mongos that can be connected to mongodb in the cloud, but only by keyFile, but I need by user/password.
Can anyone help me find an analogue of pgbouncer for mongodb or suggest another solution? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

When you say MongoDB in the cloud, are you using Mongo Atlas? If so, Teleport has native integration with Atlas.

You can utilize the following guide for it: https://goteleport.com/docs/database-access/guides/mongodb-atlas/